# Exactly The Same Autocovariance Function of Two Time Series

Tags: time-series, self-study, autocorrelation

A MA(2) process :

$$X_t=W_t+\frac{5}{2}W_{t-1}-\frac{3}{2}W_{t-2}$$

where $\{W_t\}\sim WN(0,1)$

And another MA(2) process :

$$X_t=W_t-\frac{1}{6}W_{t-1}-\frac{1}{6}W_{t-2}$$

where $\{W_t\}\sim WN(0,9)$

Both  time series have exactly the same autocovariance function .  What does it imply ? What is the message of the example ?

Answer (score 3):

> Both time series have exactly the same autocovariance function . What
>   does it imply ? What is the message of the example ?

That the autocovariance function (which is something we estimate based on the data available), in general, **does not uniquely identify the process**.

A related discussion can be found in [Jenkins and Watts (1968), "Spectral Analysis and its Applications"](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1892803038) (ch. 5.26, p. 170):

> *"A stochastic process is said to be Gaussian or Normal if the multivariate  distribution associated with an arbitrarily chosen set
>   of points is multivariate Normal. Then the process is completely
>   characterized by its mean, variance and acf (autocorrelation function). However, there will be a
>   very wide class of non-Normal processes which have the same acf as a
>   given Normal process but which differ markedly from it in other
>   respects."*

They offer a specific example after the above passage, and they conclude that higher-order moments should come into the picture.

Comment: Assuming (as is conventional) that "WN" in the question means "white noise" and that, in turn, is interpreted as iid Gaussian, then the two processes in the question are indeed Gaussian in the sense of the Jenkins and Watts quotation. It seems you have not resolved the question. You need to consider the *invertibility* of these processes.  Higher-order moments are not relevant.

Comment: @whuber My answer is "in general, the autocovariance function does not uniquely identify the process". As for the Jenkins and Watts passage, I specifically write "a _related_ discussion". I am not offering the passage as _the_ answer to the question, but as supplementary material, an example of when the acf is not unique. Certainly invertibility is focal here,  but I decided to let the OP and any interested other reader  find that out. If they don't, they weren't interested enough.

Answer (score 1):

The autocovariance function is closely related to the *autocorrelation* function of the *deterministic sequences* $\left[1 \quad \frac 52 \quad -\frac 32\right]$ and $\left[1 \quad -\frac 16 \quad -\frac 16\right]$ where the autocorrelation function of the
deterministic sequence $[x_0, x_1, \ldots, x_{N-1}]$ is defined as
$$R_x(k) = \sum_{i=0}^{N-k-1} x_i x_{i+k}, ~~ 0 \leq k \leq N-1.$$
It is not unusual for two deterministic sequences to have the same autocorrelation function.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question. The ACF or the autocovariance structure evidently will suggest the form of the ARIMA model BUT not the values of the coefficients of the ARIMA model.

Comment: This is only an MA model.  In this limited case, then, *why* does the ACF not uniquely identify the coefficients?

Comment: An ma(2) model requires that thetha2 + theta1 < 1 and thetha2-thetha1<1 and thetha2 is in the range -1 to + 1 .perhaps this is the issue